# Can you create a tipped arrow that has several potion effects on it using commands?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to make a PVP minigame, and I want to be able to have a tipped arrow with both poison and regeneration at the same time so it staggers whoever is shot every second, and is a nuisance rather than dealing damage. Is there a way to do this?

I'm in 1.16.5.

Comment: Also, I might want to also add instant health 1 on the list, but idk you can just give me the idea of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can! I suggest using the give generator on [mcstacker](https://mcstacker.net) and selecting custom potion effects at the bottom of the Tipped Arrows NBT selector.

Comment: Thanks! I made a cool arrow and I'm gonna use it in a minigame. Thank you!

Comment: you're welcome!  So you know, you can accept helpful awnsers that worked for you so other people can find them too.

Comment: I accepted it!!